# Append text to a field based on another field's value

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I want to append a text  based on another field's value. For example:-

This is the current df:

```
field_x <- c("A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C")
field_y <- c("Axl", "Slash", "Duff", "Steven", "Izzy", "Dizzy")

df <- cbind(field_x, field_y)
```

I need to change the field_y based on field_x values so that it looks like this:

```
field_x <- c("A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C")
field_y <- c("Axl (Apple)", "Slash (Apple)", "Duff (Cat)", "Steven (Ball)", "Izzy (Ball)", "Dizzy (Cat)")
```

So, basically if `field_x` has `"A"` then `"(Apple)"` is to be appended to `field_y` and so forth. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do we know that `A` becomes `Apple`, `B` becomes `Ball`, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that your df is actually a matrix: when you cbind vectors, you get a matrix. So first thing to do is convert to dataframe.
Then it depends on whether or not you are using `dplyr`.

```
field_x <- c("A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C")
field_y <- c("Axl", "Slash", "Duff", "Steven", "Izzy", "Dizzy")
df <- cbind(field_x, field_y)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

Without dplyr:

```
df <- within(df, {
  s <- ifelse(field_x == "A", "Apple", ifelse(field_x == "B", "Ball", "Cat"))
  field_y <- paste0(field_y, "(", s, ")")
  rm(s)
})
```

With dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

df %<>%
  mutate(
    s = recode(field_x, "A" = "Apple", "B" = "Ball", "C" = "Cat"),
    field_y = str_glue("{field_y}({s})")) %>%
  select(-s)
```

Another way, with `case_when` instead of `recode`:

```
df %<>%
  mutate(
    s = case_when(
      field_x == "A" ~ "Apple",
      field_x == "B" ~ "Ball",
      field_x == "C" ~ "Cat"
    ),
    field_y = str_glue("{field_y}({s})")) %>%
  select(-s)
```

Note that I create an auxiliary variable `s`: it's not really necessary, but it makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:
We could create a look-up table to address the concerns of @Tim Biegeleisen in the comment section:

```
look_up <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B" ,"C"),
           y = c("Apple", "Ball", "Cat"))


library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(field_y = paste0(field_y, ' (', look_up$y[look_up$x==field_x], ')'))
```

```
  field_x field_y      
  <chr>   <chr>        
1 A       Axl (Apple)  
2 A       Slash (Apple)
3 C       Duff (Cat)   
4 B       Steven (Ball)
5 B       Izzy (Ball)  
6 C       Dizzy (Cat)
```

Comment: Not a very good idea to use `rowwise`, which is going to loop over rows, on a possibly large dataset, just to recode a variable. Even the lookup is rather terrible: for each row, you are subseting a table. Why not a join, if you insist in going this path?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut. I am aware of your concerns. But most of them are addressed in your answer. So my answer is different and only a suggestion. In contrast in case you have many variables to recode. I personally prefer to have a look up table. Anyway thank you very much for your valuable comment!

Comment: I agree, when there are many codes, a lookup table is indeed better. But then do a `left_join`!

Comment: However, `rowwise()` isn't really necessary here? + I personally like t.o `deframe()` lookup tables into named vectors, and do: `mutate(field_y = paste0(field_y, ' (', look_up_deframed[field_x], ')'))`

Comment: Thanks a ton, Jean-Claude and TarJae!